# How to return response to a Shopify Webhook?

Tags: force.com-sites, restresource, webhooks

I have a Salesforce site which is used as a rest resource for a Shopify Webhook for new Order Creation.
When a new order is created in Shopify it hits the Url provided by us and expects a "200 OK" in response.
How can I return the required response to the webhook. Here is the document which depicts the webhook requirement:- https://help.shopify.com/en/api/getting-started/webhooks#configuring-webhooks (Please review the "Responding to a webhook" section).
Below mentioned is the code Snippet :-

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/ShopSf/Odr')
global class ShopifyRestClass {
    @HttpPost

    global static String setName(){

      System.debug('>>>>>>in rest resource');

      RestResponse response = RestContext.response;
      response.statusCode = 200;
      System.debug('>>>>>>>>>>>>>response'+response); 
      ShopifyDataSync.ShopifySyncMethod(RestContext.request,'Order'); 

        return null;

    }
```

Comment: don't forget to verify that the [webhook is coming from Shopify](https://help.shopify.com/api/tutorials/webhooks#verify-webhook).

Answer (score 2):

You have to set statuscode and response text blob in `RestContext.response`

```
 RestResource(urlMapping='/ShopSf/Odr')
    global class ShopifyRestClass {
        @HttpPost

        global static void setName(){

          System.debug('>>>>>>in rest resource');
          System.debug('>>>>>>>>>>>>>response'+response); 
          ShopifyDataSync.ShopifySyncMethod(RestContext.request,'Order'); 
          RestContext.response.statusCode = 200;
          RestContext.response.responseBody = Blob.valueOf('OK');    

        }
```

Src: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_restresponse.htm#apex_methods_system_restresponse

Comment: I think you meant RestContext.response, not RestContext.request.

Comment: Thanks for the edit @Ohana

Comment: @PranayJaiswal thanks for the input, but still the webhook is getting hit multiple times. This is not working.

Comment: Thats diffrent issue isnt it

Comment: No, because the webhook hits again the rest resource url if it does not receive 200 OK response back (retry mechanism) as mentioned in the question description document.